# RecyclerView Adapter, OnclickListener on a fragment inside an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEkvbCTYun8 to set an Onclicklistener method. However in the tutorial, the projects works because everything is made on an activity. I'm trying to adapt the code to work on a recyclerview inside a fragment and set it the onclicklistener. But when I made everything throws me an error while casting the activity to the interface.

The original code to create the adapter referencing the MainActivity(From video):

```
mMediaStoreAdapter=new MediaStoreAdapter(this);
```

Mine:

```
mMediaStoreAdapter=new MediaStoreAdapter(getActivity());
```

The constructor and the interface:

```
private OnClickThumbListener mOnClickThumbListener;

    public interface OnClickThumbListener {
        void OnClickImage(Uri imageUri);
    }

    public MediaStoreAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mOnClickThumbListener=(OnClickThumbListener)activity;
    }
```

I don't get what I'm making wrong, the error shows that cast ((OnClickThumbListener)activity) is not possible. Maybe the that's not the correct approach on that, or should add the interface object as a parameter on constructor? On the tutorial works fine. Please somebody give me a guidance on this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving Activity in your constructor, can you try your Context? 
Please try this.

```
public MediaStoreAdapter(Context activity)
```

I think it should work.